# Exporting a function inside a function

Tags: node.js, node-modules

app.js

```
var a = function(){
      var b = function(){
          console.log("hello")
      }
}

module.exports = {a}
```

index.js

```
console.log(require("./app.js").a().b())
```

I wantr to get the output "hello" but i am getting error `can call property b of undefined`
Please help to obtain the result

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
var a = function () {
    var b = function () {
        console.log("hello")
    }
    return {b:b};
}
```

Comment: thanx u save my day